# How to account for serial correlation in probability of at least one event?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation

Say I want the probability of at least 1 event occurring out of a series of `n` events each with differing but known probabilities from observing past behavior `p_0, p_1, ... p_n`. Generally, if I assume all of these events are independent, I can get that for some share of the events via 1 - the product of all `(1 - p_i)` in my probability pool.

But now let's say closer inspection of the original events from which I derived by probabilities shows serial correlation was strong. For instance, if an event happened at step `t` in the event chain, it was more likely to happen at `t + 1`. If I then re-asked (say for some new, similar experiment), what's the probability of at least one event, it doesn't make sense that I can use the basic probability formulation above, correct? Should  I account for that serial correlation in some way, and if so, how so?